# Yii2 frontend/config/bootstrap.php is rewriting

Tags: php, yii2

Just start editing new project based on `Yii 2`. I am used to `Yii 1`.
Just for test, added string `echo 'test';` to the file frontend/config/bootstrap.php.
Then I saw this string on my website. So then I removed it from `frontend/config/bootstrap.php`.
Unfortunately, now `frontend/config/bootstrap.php` contains the test string again. I tried to remove the string several times,
but it appears again and again after 5 minutes of my operation. Why? 
I tried to clear Yii cache by the console, it did not help

Comment: thats weird. check maybe the edited file is not getting saved on the server when you are pushing it

Comment: are you working on the local system ?

Comment: it is not Yii2 problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from reading up on Yii 2 environments and configs.

> The init command is used to initialize an environment. What it really does is copy everything from the environment directory over to the root directory where all applications are.

Essentially, files you may be editing are actually the result of Yii copying to the production location. Be sure to edit the correct set of config files and then rerun the init command.

https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-environments